# how to set rxtx with OSGi Equinox?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, rxtx

I am looking for a solution to my problem.
I am developing a bundle that has to read from the serial port by means of rxtx jar.
When I launch the application, I get the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at ez430.Port.<init>(Port.java:29)
```

I have added the jar to build path and set it in the jVM.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Since OSGi is multi-platform and needs to take care of appearing and disappearing bundles, the handling of native libraries (as rxtx does) needs to be explicitly specified for a bundle. That is done using a `Bundle-NativeCode` header in the bundle that includes the rxtx jar file. The native library to load can be indicated per os and architecture. In this case it may look like:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so; 
  osname="Linux";processor="x86-64",
  lib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxSerial.dll;
  osname="Windows"
```

The above example indicates that for Linux x86-64 the library can be found in `lib/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so` and for Windows (all architectures) in `lib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxSerial.dll`. Paths are relative in the bundle, therefore don't forget to include the shared libraries in your bundle.

For further details, look in  the [OSGi core](http://www.osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.core-6.0.0.pdf) specification.