# Unresolved requirement when integrating RXTX to OSGi bundle on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, osgi, equinox, rxtx

Related: [Installing rxtx bundle in my Raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936314/installing-rxtx-bundle-in-my-raspberry)

[how to set rxtx with OSGi Equinox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739459/how-to-set-rxtx-with-osgi-equinox)

[rxtx-osgi code depot](https://github.com/whizzosoftware/rxtx-osgi)

I am trying to use the RXTX Java (JRE 1.8) library from within an OSGi bundle on a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian (Stretch).

Everything works fine on Windows (Seven, x64), but on Raspbian starting the bundle throws an *Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability* error.

> gogo: BundleException: Could not resolve module: lerna.plugins.serial_interface [6]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.native; native.paths.8:List="nativelib/Windows/mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64/rxtxParallel.dll,nativelib/Windows/mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64/rxtxSerial.dll"; native.paths.7:List="nativelib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxParallel.dll,nativelib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxSerial.dll"; native.paths.0:List="nativelib/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxParallel.so,nativelib/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so"; native.paths.2:List="nativelib/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so"; native.paths.1:List="nativelib/Linux/ia64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so"; native.paths.4:List="nativelib/Mac_OS_X/librxtxSerial.jnilib"; native.paths.3:List="nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxParallel.so,nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxSerial.so"; native.paths.6:List="nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so,nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so"; native.paths.5:List="nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so,nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so"; filter:="(|(&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ia64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=armv6l))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Mac OS X)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=PowerPC)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Solaris)(osgi.native.processor~=Sparc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Solaris)(osgi.native.processor~=Sparc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=Win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)))"

I assume there's something wrong with the way I've included the armv6l native binaries into the bundle, but for the life of me I can't find where the problem is.

The content of the bundle itself doesn't matter, as long as it uses RXTX.

The complete MANIFEST.MF follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Serial_interface
Bundle-SymbolicName: lerna.plugins.serial_interface
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: lerna.plugins.serial_interface.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: telecom_bretagne
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: lerna.common,
 lerna.common.exceptions,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: src/,
 .,
 bin/,
 libs/RXTXcomm.jar
Bundle-NativeCode: 
 nativelib/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxParallel.so;
 nativelib/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=x86,

 nativelib/Linux/ia64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=ia64,

 nativelib/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=x86-64,

 nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxParallel.so;
 nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=armv6l,

 nativelib/Mac_OS_X/librxtxSerial.jnilib;
 osname=Mac OS X; processor=x86; processor=PowerPC; processor=x86-64,


 nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so;
 nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Solaris; processor=Sparc,

 nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so;
 nativelib/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Solaris; processor=Sparc64,


 nativelib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxParallel.dll;
 nativelib/Windows/i368-mingw32/rxtxSerial.dll;
 osname=Win32; processor=x86,

 nativelib/Windows/mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64/rxtxParallel.dll;
 nativelib/Windows/mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64/rxtxSerial.dll;
 osname=Win32; processor=x86-64
Export-Package: gnu.io,
 lerna.plugins.serial_interface
```

This MANIFEST.MF works just fine for Windows, and I've found at least two separate sources using the same entries for ARMv6 and RXTX (references at top).

The binaries are well and truly present in the nativelibs/ folder:

[nativelibs folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT0nS.png)
(I do not have enough reputation to embed an image, so have a link instead)

The binaries for armv6l were pulled straight out of /usr/lib/jni, from the very Raspberry Pi I'm trying to run the bundle on. Those binaries were downloaded through apt-get, and I can run RXTX code outside of an OSGi bundle so I assume those binaries are correct.

At this point, I've ran out of ideas on what I might have done wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your time.

## Edit 1

As requested, I am posting the results of
`inspect cap osgi.native 0`
in the Gogo shell. However, it appears those bundles are not loaded by my basic environment. They were not required on Windows, could they be an extra dependency for Linux/armv6l?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/lerna/release $ java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321.jar -console
ss
osgi> "Framework is launched."


id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321
1       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
2       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
3       ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
4       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.300.v20170512-2111
osgi> inspect cap osgi.native 0
Invalid argument: cap
Invalid argument: osgi.native
osgi>
```

I suppose it is quite obvious now I am not really familiar with OSGi...

Additional information:

configuration/config.ini file:

```
osgi.bundles=org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime@start, org.apache.felix.gogo.command@start, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell@start, org.eclipse.equinox.console@start
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
osgi.noShutdown=true
osgi.console.enable.builtin=true
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
```

Comment: It looks like your bundle does not match the native capabilities of the platform, as exposed by the system bundle. If you are running the Gogo shell in your framework, please enter the command `inspect cap osgi.native 0` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the OP.

Comment: So the `inspect` command didn't work, probably because you are using very old versions of the Gogo bundles. I expected it to show the `osgi.native` capability provided by the system bundle, which would have had a `processor` attribute on it that needed to match the `processor` attribute in one of the `Bundle-Native` entries. Anyway I'm glad that you have found the solution via another route.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. I was indeed an issue with the MANIFEST.MF file. Neil Bartlett's answer hinted there was an issue related to osgi.native, and as I dug deeper I found [this](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf-running-on-ARM-RaspberryPi-td4049883.html). It is unrelated to RXTX, but there someone said:

> I also found the cause of the second issue. It seems as the the processor type of 'arm_le' is not recognised by the system bundle. I delved into the the Apache felix code and it looks as though it uses the result returned by 'system.getProperty("os.arch") which on the Pi is 'arm'.

I was aware of the 'ARM' (deprecated) architecture for OSGi, as it is in the [official reference](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference). I even tried it.
What I did not know, however, was that the reference is apparently wrong: it should be lowercase, as in 'arm'.

Now my MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
 nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxParallel.so;
 nativelib/Linux/armv6l/librxtxSerial.so;
 osname=Linux; processor=arm,
```

And it works.
I still need to test the library in depth, but at least now it's loading.

Still, I wonder why 'armv6l' does not work with my Raspberry Pi B / Raspbian (Stretch), even though it worked for other people on SO.

Comment: It's legal to list multiple `processor` attributes here so you might want to add both `arm` and `arm_le`. In this way, your bundle will work on JVMs that correctly report `arm_le` for the `os.arch` system property.

Comment: Also you might want to investigate why the JVM is returning the `os.arch` as `arm`. Which Java version is it?

Comment: Finally (sorry for so many comments!) I'm surprised that it didn't work when you specified `ARM` instead of `arm`. The matching on this attribute is meant to be case-insensitive.

Comment: It's not supposed to be case sensitive, but it's not supposed to return 'arm' instead of 'armv6l' either. I still have no idea where this issue comes from. Perhaps it is a peculiarity of Raspbian Stretch on the old RPi B+?
JRE version is 1.8, installed from apt depots. OSGi JAR versions are in the OP, but I pulled them from a squicky-clean Eclipse JEE Oxygen install so they can't be _that_ out of date.

Comment: My point was that if you put `ARM` in your `Bundle-Native` header then it should match `arm` from the system because the match is case-insensitive. It should be obvious that `armv6l` won't match, irrespective of case!